# Python List object has no attribute position

Tags: python, list, attributeerror

I receive this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Pozitie'` when I try to run my code, I have a list inside of a class and inside of it I have objects of another class, which needs three parameters: two tuples and a list, I'm trying to pass as a parameter the list inside my first class. I'm pretty new to python and I've tried everything I could think of, some help would be appreciated thanks.
Here is my code, sorry for the variable names not being english:

```
class StareJoc():
  def __init__(self): 
    
    self.Pozitie = [  
        
      ["Negru_Tura", "Negru_Cal", "Negru_Nebun", "Negru_Regina", "Negru_Rege", "Negru_Nebun",   "Negru_Cal", "Negru_Tura"],
       
      ["Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion","Negru_Pion"],
        
      ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        
      ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        
      ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
       
      ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        
      ["Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion"],
       
      ["Alb_Tura", "Alb_Cal", "Alb_Nebun", "Alb_Regina", "Alb_Rege", "Alb_Nebun", "Alb_Cal", "Alb_Tura"]]
      
   def Toate_Mutarile_Posibile(self):
    mutari = [Mutare((6, 4), (4, 4), self.Pozitie)]  #<--- I want to pass in the list "Pozitie" from above, 
                                                     #but I get the error 'list' object has no attribute 'Pozitie'
    for rand in range(len(self.Pozitie)):
        for coloana in range(len(self.Pozitie[rand])):
            randul = self.Pozitie[rand][coloana][0]
            if (randul == 'A' and self.Mutare_Alb) or (randul == 'N' and not self.Mutare_Alb):
                piesa = self.Pozitie[rand][coloana]
                if piesa.find('Pion') != -1:
                    self.MutariPion(rand, coloana, mutari)
                elif piesa.find('Tura') != -1:
                    self.MutariTura(rand, coloana, mutari)
    return mutari

class Mutare():

   def __init__(self, Patrat_Start, Patrat_Destinatie, Pozitie_Curenta): #args: self, tuple, tuple, list
    #(some code)
```

Comment: It'd help if you provided a working [mre] so that we could see the error for ourselves. In that case you could change it all to be English, and leave out all irrelevant parts.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you are doing something like `StareJoc.Toate_Mutarile_Posibile(StareJob.Pozitie)` which would actually result in that error.

Answer (score 0):

In your code define the constant outside the *init*_ method :

```
class StareJoc():
  Pozitie = [  
    
  ["Negru_Tura", "Negru_Cal", "Negru_Nebun", "Negru_Regina", "Negru_Rege", "Negru_Nebun",   "Negru_Cal", "Negru_Tura"],
   
  ["Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion", "Negru_Pion","Negru_Pion"],
    
  ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
    
  ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
    
  ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
   
  ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
    
  ["Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion", "Alb_Pion"],
   
  ["Alb_Tura", "Alb_Cal", "Alb_Nebun", "Alb_Regina", "Alb_Rege", "Alb_Nebun", "Alb_Cal", "Alb_Tura"]]
```